# Query to filter records based on specific conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

> There is a table a_status_check with the following data:

[image]

The requirement is: If status LC and BE both are present, then consider only LC. Otherwise, consider BE. Ignore other codes for that id.

So, the result should be like:

[image]

I tried DECODE and CASE functions with no luck. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use analytical functions:

```
select distinct
  id,
  first_value (status) over (partition by id order by status desc) status,
  first_value (amt   ) over (partition by id order by status desc) amt
from
  tq84_a_status_check
where
  status in ('LC', 'BE')
order by
  id;
```

Testdata:

```
create table tq84_a_status_check (
  id number,
  status varchar2(10),
  amt number
);

select distinct
  id,
  first_value (status) over (partition by id order by status desc) status,
  first_value (amt   ) over (partition by id order by status desc) amt
from
  tq84_a_status_check
where
  status in ('LC', 'BE')
order by
  id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. But values A and B in status have been used for the mocked up example and actual scenario may contain more than 1 statuses with different names out of which I have to consider only two. Modifying the question to explain.

Comment: If only `BE` and `LC` are interesting, you filter them first with `where status in ...` and use the analytical functions, as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT id, status, amt
FROM yourTable yt
INNER JOIN (
        -- get only max
        SELECT id, MAX(status) as status
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY id
    ) as onlyMax
      ON yt.id = onlyMax.id
      AND yt.status = onlyMax.status
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work assuming you only have two `STATUS` values (A and B).  I first obtain a temporary table containing the `STATUS` counts for each `ID` and then I `JOIN` this back to `a_status_check`.  The `WHERE` clause retains the `A` records when they appear alone, and it retains the `B` records when `A` and `B` appear together.

```
SELECT * FROM a_status_check t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS status_count
    FROM a_status_check
    GROUP BY ID
) t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE (t1.STATUS = 'A' AND t2.status_count = 1)
    OR (t1.STATUS = 'B' AND t2.status_count = 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id, status, amt
FROM a_status_check t
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT id, MAX(status) as status
        FROM a_status_check
        GROUP BY id
    ) as a
      ON t.id = a.id
      AND t.status = a.status
```